# Nginx config error error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

Tags: django, nginx

Hello all I am new to nginx and am in serious need of help I am configuring my setup based on Digital Oceans [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#configure-nginx-to-proxy-pass-to-gunicorn). I know I messed up somewhere I have read countless docs and maybe I missed something. I believe it is where my root directory is pointed to or how I set it up. Here is my code:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name www.xxx.com;
  include snippets/ssl-xxx.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  root /home/sammy/myproject/profiles/templates;
  index index.html index.htm home home.html;

  root /var/www/html;

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location /static/ {
    root /home/sammy/expo/static/;
  }

  location /static/admin/ {
      #default_type text/javascript;
      alias /home/sammy/static/static-only/admin/;
  }

  location /media/ {
      alias /home/sammy/static/media/;
  }

  location / {
      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/myproject.sock;
  }
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using Django also if that helps in anyway.

Comment: please can you try to use full path names for ' include snippets/ssl-xxx.com.conf;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;' and the certificate paths in that files should also be full qualified.

Comment: You have `root` duplicated in the `server` block, but not actually used. Test your configuration using `nginx -t`.